# Regex expression to replace text between start and end characters, but keep characters too

Tags: c#, regex

How can I replace text using c# regex that starts with "<" and ends with ">", but keep start and end characters and suround found match with {} brackets? 
All occurrences in text should be replaced.
For example:
`This is <my> long <text>` should become
`This is {<my>} long {<text>}`.

Comment: No need for Regex: `s = s.Replace("<", "{<").Replace(">", ">}");`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need regex example. Couldn't figure out one that works.

Comment: @vs77 Why when there's an easy built in method to handle this would you want to complicate matters with a regular expression?  Also why does your example have encoded < and > values?

Comment: Nothing in your question needs Regex. Please tell us why you need a Regex, since that may have an impact on the solution.

Comment: I'll use similar regex text replacement later in my code. This was just for testing purpose. Thank you anyway.
@juharr Sorry for encoded < and > values. I'm still not familiar with editor on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thomas is correct -- in this case, you do not need a regular expression. However, if you insist on using one (or want to expand this logic in the future to handle a range of characters), here it is:

```
var inputString = "This is <my> long <text>";
var newInputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, "(<[^>]+>)", "{$1}");
```

This regex assumes you are capturing at least one character between the angled brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use just `replace`;

```
string text = "This is <my> long <text>";
var replacedText = text.Replace("<", "{<").Replace(">", ">}");
```

If you have encoded text, you can decode it first;

```
string text = "This is &lt;my&gt; long &lt;text&gt";
var replacedText = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text).Replace("<", "{<").Replace(">", ">}");
```